# Getting un-wanted underlining in between my font awesome icon and my anchor text

Tags: css, laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-blade

I'm using TailwindCSS and font awesome icons.  I want the icon to be part of my link but I want the underlining to end where the text ends and not hang over towards the icon.  So in the screenshot going left, stop at the u.  Any idea how?

[image: screenshot]

Some code:

```
<a href="{{ route('dashboard.profile.index', array($user->username) ) }}">
    <span class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> {{ $user->username }}
</a>
```

I tried adding no underline styling to the icon span and that didn't help.  My span is already an inline-block.

I found 2 older posts similar to this but the fiddles didn't work or no screenshots.

Comment: Try removing the space between the `</span>` and `{{` and putting it inside the span